# Error When trying to run my C# WPF and C++ Project

Tags: c#, visual-studio, game-engine

hey there I've just now started making a engine with tutorials while I was doing so I stumbled upon a error.
Here Is What the Error Told:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'ProjectBrowserDialg' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   Editor  C:\Users\abrus\OneDrive\Documents\cpp_files_me\MehroofEngine\src\MehroofEngine For C++\Editor\MainWindow.xaml.cs    37  Active
```

this is the code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;


namespace Editor
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Loaded += OnMainWindowLoaded;
        }
        private void OnMainWindowLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Loaded -= OnMainWindowLoaded;
            OpenProjectBrowserDialog();
        }

        private void OpenProjectBrowserDialog()
        {
            var projectBrowser = new ProjectBrowserDialg();
        }

        
    }
}
```

if I forgot something in the code please reply

if not enough information please reply it helps me make better posts.

Comment: Does following folder exist on machine : C:\Users\abrus\OneDrive\Documents\cpp_files_me\MehroofEngine\src\MehroofEngine?

Comment: Seems that no aditional components is included by using, so there must be some class with the name _ProjectBrowserDialg_  (orcould be a typo  and you forgot a 'o'  ) but you didn't have that class inside the namespace

Comment: @J.Salas In the tutorial there wasn't any extra 'using' files I've also tried adding the 'o' but it did nothing but I also found 2nd error where it could not find a file called WindowClass.g.cs maybe I should have a 2nd look at that if you don't recognize the file in WPF I can double check.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs0246 This error message clearly states that you are missing a file.